# How to avoid a NULL insert after update a table with Stored Procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have the following table named Paciente:

```
CREATE TABLE Paciente
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    Folio CHAR(6) UNIQUE NULL,
    Nombre NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    S_Nombre NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    Apellido_Paterno NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Apellido_Materno NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Edad SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Sexo CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    Calle NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    Numero_Domicilio SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED NULL,
    Telefono CHAR(8) NULL,
    Movil CHAR(10) NULL,
    Ocupacion NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    Fecha_Registro DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Estado BOOLEAN NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
    EstadoCivil_ID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

And the Stored Procedure for update:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `actualizarPaciente`
(
IN _param_id INT,
IN _calle NVARCHAR(50),
IN _numdomicilio SMALLINT(4),
IN _telefono CHAR(8),
IN _movil CHAR(10),
IN _ecivil INT 
)
BEGIN
UPDATE Paciente 
SET Calle = (_calle), Numero_Domicilio = (_numdomicilio), Telefono = (_telefono), Movil = (_movil), EstadoCivil_ID = (_ecivil)
WHERE ID = _param_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is this: When I want to update the patient's data, they will not always be the same, nor the same amount, they can be 2 or 4, then if I only want to update 2 of the 5 parameters and the rest keep without changes, for example the Telefono and Movil fields, in my table "disappears"  the rest of the data that were already stored ih that row.

I know that MySQL takes NULL as a valid value, but I don't know how to avoid it, I had this modification but it still doesn't work.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `actualizarPaciente`
(
IN _param_id INT,
IN _calle NVARCHAR(50),
IN _numdomicilio SMALLINT(4),
IN _telefono CHAR(8),
IN _movil CHAR(10),
IN _ecivil INT 
)
BEGIN
UPDATE Paciente 
SET Calle = COALESCE(_calle, Calle), Numero_Domicilio = COALESCE(_numdomicilio, Numero_Domicilio), Telefono = COALESCE(_telefono, Telefono), Movil = COALESCE(_movil, Movil), EstadoCivil_ID = COALESCE(_ecivil, EstadoCivil_ID)
WHERE ID = _param_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: are you able initialize these variables to NULL
.........................................
IN _calle NVARCHAR(50),
IN _numdomicilio SMALLINT(4),
IN _telefono CHAR(8),
IN _movil CHAR(10),
IN _ecivil INT

Comment: The second form *does* work.  If it isn't working for you, then I suspect you are passing empty strings, not `NULL`.